# postgresql - update - visibility of function

Tags: function, postgresql, visibility

Say I have a function *copy(in integer, out integer)* which creates in table *mytable* a duplicate of the row identified by the in-parameter. The identifier of the new row is returned.

I would like to apply an UPDATE to the new/duplicate row, instead of the old row:

```
update mytable set field = ... where identifier = (select copy(1));
```

This doesn't seem to work. The duplicate is created, but it still has the old values. I expect that the new row isn't visible yet when the where clause is evaluated. That is, no update is happening.

The following doesn't work either:

```
update mytable set field = ... from copy(1) as c where identifier = c.copy;
```

When I write it in two lines, it works perfectly:

```
select copy(1);
update mytable set field = ... where identifier = <value returned by copy(1)>;
```

I have two questions:

(1) Can this be done in a one-liner?

(2) Is it possible to write a rewrite rule or trigger such that I even can write

```
update mytable set field = ... where identifier = 1;
```

while the duplicate is created in the background and the updates are applied on the duplicate/new row? I cannot see a solution which doesn't end up in an endless loop.

**sample code**

```
drop table if exists t cascade;

create table t
(
    identifier  serial  primary key,
    title       text
);

create or replace function copy(in integer, out integer) as
$$
        begin
                insert into t (title) values ((select title from t where identifier = $1)) returning identifier into $2;
        end
$$ language plpgsql;

insert into t (title) values ('title - old');
update t set title = 'title - new' where identifier = (select copy(1));
select * from t;
```

Please note that in *copy()* the row is normally fetched into a seperate variable. For simplicity, I fetched the title directly in this sample code.

Comment: Can you post the `copy()` function code?

Comment: Kev, I added some sample code to illustrate this. Please note that this is quick&dirty, but it explains my question, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not working for the same reason that you cannot use returning in with statements except from PG 9.1 onwards. This should work fine in 9.1:

```
drop table if exists t cascade;

create table t (
    identifier  serial  primary key,
    title       text
);

insert into t (title) values ('title - old');

with copy as (
insert into t (title) select title from t where identifier = 1
returning identifier
)
update t set title = 'title - new' from copy where t.identifier = copy.identifier;

select * from t;
```

---

Edited: possible 9.0 suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Stripped. Thanks for checking (I can't, on the iPad).

Comment: I tried your suggestion with 9.1 beta 3 and it still returns a new row but the old title. (I hadd to add 'from copy' in the update statement). Any ideas?

Comment: @Potige: I've amended it to add the from clause, and just tested it -- it's working fine in 9.1 beta3.